# Is it possible to 'nest' themes in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a React app which uses the Material UI Theme Provider to set the font throughout, like this:

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        ... routes rendering various elements ...
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

const ThemedApp = () => {
  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: Colours.primaryColor,
      },
      secondary: {
        main: Colours.secondaryColor,
      },
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: 'serif',
      fontSize: 16,
    },
  });
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

const FirebaseApp = () => {
  return <ThemedApp />;
};

export default FirebaseApp;
```

(I didn't write this code, so I'm not sure why it exports ThemedApp as FirebaseApp instead of just renaming ThemedApp to FirebaseApp or something, but that's a different issue).

However, one section of the app (we'll call it 'DifferentFontArea') needs to use a different font, but the rest of the theme is the same.  I've tried 'nesting' the ThemeProvider like this (this component is a child of the App component shown above, and therefor wrapped within ThemeProvider):

```
const DifferentFontBase = () => {

    return (
      <>
        ... component details go here
      </>
    );
  }

};

const DifferentFontArea = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const fontTheme = createTheme({
    ...theme,
    typography: {
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    },
  });
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={fontTheme}>
      <DifferentFontBase />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default DifferentFontArea;
```

This seems to work; when DifferentArea is rendered, it has a sans-serif font, whereas the rest of the app has the serif font.  I'm just not sure whether it's ok to nest providers like this, as I can't find references to it in the documentation.

Comment: You can always override style inside your components, so that you can specify a different font than what's in the theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components will use the closest provider for any context they are referencing.  This means the `theme` created in `ThemedApp` is not visible, in any sense of the word, to the components inside `<DifferentFontBase />`, as all the components inside will be referencing the value from closer provider, i.e. `fontTheme`.

Whether it's okay or not depends on your use case. It seems that, in the scenario you posted, since `fontTheme` references the original `theme`, you should be okay.

Comment: Thank you... it's maybe such a basic thing that it's not often stated explicitly!